# How to set Log Pattern in log4j2-spring.xml to log Class Method and Line

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I am trying to set log pattern to print Class Method and line in log file. Below is my Configuration. Its working fine with Console but not working with Async

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%d [%thread] [%-5level] [%class{36}.%M %L] [Content-Id:%X{contentId}] [Request-Id:%X{requestId}] [%c{1.}] - %msg%n" />
    <Property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs" />
    <Property name="SYSTEM_FILE" value="application.log" />
</Properties>
<Appenders>

    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
    </Console>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
    </Async>

    <RollingFile name="FileAppender"
        fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${SYSTEM_FILE}"
        filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/${SYSTEM_FILE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="com.myproject" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
    </Logger>
    
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I am using this **[%class{36}.%M %L]** pattern to log Class Method and line.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You should log the line number this makes logging much slower https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#LocationInformation

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the caller location is an expensive operation in Java. It always requires some sort of stack walking.

If everything is synchronous Log4j retrieves location lazily, whenever needed. But if either the appender or the logger are asynchronous, the location must be retrieved before jumping threads. For asynchronous elements this slows down logging 5 to 20 times. This is why location is **disabled** by default in these cases.

You can enable location with the `includeLocation` property:

- for an async appender use:

  ```xml
  <Async name="Async" includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
  </Async>
  ```
- for an async logger (requires additional dependencies, cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)) use:

  ```xml
  <AsyncLogger name="com.myproject"
               level="DEBUG"
               additivity="false"
               includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </AsyncLogger>
  ```

An alternative solution (if you are using Maven) is to use the recently released `log4j-transform-maven-plugin`, which computes the location at compile-time, so the runtime lookup is no longer necessary and location is always available. Just add it to your POM file (cf. [documentation](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-transform/blob/main/log4j-transform-maven-plugin/README.adoc)):

```xml
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-transform-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process-classes</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the main author of the `log4j-maven-transform-plugin`.